# Adding HTML to the end of a container: What is the proper way to do it using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a bit of a web dev n00b, so I do things like this:

```
document.getElementById("some_element").innerHTML += "<p>Here's some more that will be added to the end of the HTML that composes some_element</p>";
```

However, I'm guessing there's a purer way of accomplishing the task of modifying inner HTML. What is the standard way of doing this? I assume this sort of procedure is what happens when I post something on an internet forum. So, it's kind of an important thing to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using `appendChild` over `innerHTML`

```
myDiv = document.getElementById("myid");
myNewNode = document.createElement("div")
myContent = document.createTextNode("text of new div");
myNewNode.appendChild(myContent);
myDiv.appendChild(myNewNode);
```

`innerHTML` will remove listeners that are on your existing nodes within the element.  `appendChild` preserves them.

Comment: Why are you passing HTML to `createTextNode()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create and append nodes via HTML markup, do so by using `.insertAdjacentHTML()`.

```
elem.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>Here's some more that will be added to the end of the HTML that composes some_element</p>");
```

---

Otherwise, use DOM creation/manipulation methods.

```
elem.appendChild(document.createElement("p"))
    .appendChild(document.createTextNode("Here's some more that will be added to the end of the HTML that composes some_element"));
```